# Is SublimeLinter giving me the correct errors?

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublimetext 3 and [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/) (along with [SublimeLinter-php](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-php)) to lint my files. I've never used this plugin before (nor have I used IDE's extensively in PHP) and I'm seeing SublimeLinter show errors like this in my code: (some laravel code)
[image: sublime text sublimelinter errors]

These are the errors I'm getting for each of those lines:

- 11: undeclared parent class Controller
- 12: undefined identifier 'Request'
- 14: unknown class Post
- 19: unresolved function response

Are these actual errors that SublimeLinter should have picked up? Or is my [configuration](http://pastebin.com/qBVN6pUF) for SublimeLinter wrong which is causing it to pick up these lines as errors by mistake?

Comment: It seems more that your sublime (or the sublimelinter) did not index all classes/functions of laravel. All this stuff is autoloaded in laravel, so if it only inspects this file, then its obvious that it thinks there are those errors.

Comment: Is indexing done automatically or does it have to be done manually by the user? I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was happening because I did not have a sublime project set up.

A project can be set up my clicking `Project > Save Project As...` from the project menu drop down

Comment: Did you do something after setting up the project? It didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: I don't think I did anything else. I had this problem so long ago I don't remember to be honest.